# Constant-time comparison of hash functions in PHP

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to verify whether a string matches a SHA-512 (Unix) hash ($6$..) in PHP. Much like the `password_verify()` function for Blowfish (BCrypt) but for SHA-512 (Unix) instead.

I stumbled upon `hash_equals` which tends to compare two strings using the same time. However, I am unable to get the expected output `boolean true` on the following:

```
<?php

$expected  = '$6$9e87b0c78da9ab83$5V16BLuWUkoG3g1oH3kwhs8rzBpjydUps1qBXuY3PkkFzDSjqklT47L5pmG8JPqDRDk.ZTJoS/ogtHkyXC2L40';

if (CRYPT_SHA512 == 1) {
    $correct = crypt('OkvraMADvua', '$6$12$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
}

var_dump(hash_equals($expected, $correct));

?>
```

Right now, I get `boolean false` even though the hash value of `$expected` corresponds to the plaintext and the hash generated for the `$correct` variable also matches that same plaintext (OkvraMADvua).

- The issue is that the salt is always different and that is to be expected with crypt(3) algorithms. Whenever I use the same salt, it's evident that the output would be `boolean true`.

Comment: Can you show how `$expected` is calculated? Are you using the same salt?

Comment: Your `$expected` should read as `$expected  = crypt('OkvraMADvua', '$6$12$usesomesillystringforsalt$');` - question's unclear though.

Comment: hi, i am getting different hashes here: [link](https://3v4l.org/oTa47) so i think sha512 is not using or you have wrongly formatted salt/numberOfRounds

Comment: The issue is that the salt is always different and that is to be expected with crypt(3) algorithms. Whenever I use the same salt it's evident that the output would be `boolean true`.

Comment: All `hash_equal` does is compare two strings and is certain to take the same time to execute whether they match or not. i.e. it is a constant time to execute, `string compare`, function. It is used to prevent `timing attacks` against your security checking code. Your issue seems to be that `$expected` and `$correct` contain different strings? This is nothing to do with 'hash_equal'? debugging: `var_dump($expected, $correct, $expected === $correct);` are they different? Should they be the same?

Comment: In which case I would assume that I cannot achieve what I am after in PHP, correct?